# jQuery .change to load different .php file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, smarty

My project is in PHP / MySQL. I'm using Smarty for a template engine.

I have a < select > tag in my smarty file:

maps.tpl -

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <form method="post" action="maps.php">

        <td colspan="3">

            <select id="cmdview" name="cmd">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="commdata" {if $cmdOn == "commdata"}selected="true"{/if}>Communications</option>
                <option value="contacts" {if $cmdOn == "contacts"}selected="true"{/if}>Contacts</option>
                <option value="enrollment" {if $cmdOn == "enrollment"}selected="true"{/if}>Enrollment</option>
                <option value="all" {if $cmdOn == "all"}selected="true"{/if}>All Schools</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" name="doSwitch" value="Submit" />

        </td>

        <div id="append"></div2>

    </form>
```

So far, my jQuery code finds which value is selected:

```
{literal}

<script>
$('#cmdview').change(function() {
    //alert('Handler for .change() called.');
        var str = "";
        url = "maps_append.php";

        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
           });
        $('#append').text(str);
            })
            .change();
</script>
{/literal}
```

I need the jQuery to listen for the value of "cmdview" then post that value to file: maps_append.php . I need that file to .append/.change the current file (maps.php/maps.tpl) without reloading.

But, my jQuery is only half working. The jQuery does find the value I'm trying to pass, and I've gotten it to load that correct value in the <.d.i.v.> tag with id #append . The only thing I can't seem to do is that take value and actually post it to maps_append.php

Any help will be very appreciated!

Thank you!

PS: I think the change will be something like this:

This needs to be replaced:

```
    $('#append').text(str);
        })
        .change();
```

With something like this:

```
url = "maps_append.php";
    $.post( url, { cmd: cmdview, value: str } ,
        function( data ) {
            var content = $( data );

          $( "#result" ).append( content );
      }
    );
    $term_input.val('');
});
```

**EDIT::**

My current file is maps.php. I now have it appending maps_append.php to maps.php with this code:

```
<script>
$('#cmdview').change(function() {
    //alert('Handler for .change() called.');
        var str = "";
            url = "maps_append.php";
        url = "maps_append.php";

        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
           });
        $('#append').load(url);
            })
            .change();
</script>
```

I just need to post the value of the select tag now!

**Closer still... please see this edit:**

```
  <script>
    $('#cmdview').change(function() {
        //alert('Handler for .change() called.');
            var str = "";
                url = "maps_append.php";
            $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
               });
            $.post( url, { str: "$cmdOn" } , 
                function( data ) {
                    var content = $( data );
            $('#append').load(url);
                })
                .change();

                    });
    </script>
```

Now the maps_append.php page only appends to maps.php when I change the value of the select tag. I only need to include the value of the select tag when maps_append.php appears now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the details of what you are doing here -- all the code looks fine but the plan seems a little strange.

Typically you don't have a program change the source.  Instead you would have code store data in a database and the code would be driven by the database to produce different output.

Maybe this is what you want to do with the content -- store it in a database and have a page that displays it.

---

To load content via jQuery use the following

```
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {
    $(""+elementSelector+"").load("http://yoursite.com/"+sourceURL+"");
}
```

See this link: http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/load-remote-content-into-div-element.html

Comment: On what option is selected, criteria is appended to the page. If "enrolment" is selected value, a different form input will append. If "contacts" is selected, another input will appear. 

"enrollment" is selected, data needs to be limited size of class. So, I need a form input w/ an integer - text input will work.

If "communication" value is selected, I need a timestamp value. So, I load a calendar applet or just have a date/month/year select .append to page. 

I need more form inputs appear, but WHAT form inputs depends on what the user selects.

Comment: You typically would not change the PHP page.  Remember more than one user can use the page at the same time.  The typical way to do this with AJAX is to just append to the current HTML.  You might also save progress so if a user came back later you could construct the page correctly.  In the 2nd case you would need a database.

Comment: Saving the progress of the current user so that his/her search values remain is something that would be nice to have -- but, right now it's not the primary problem. I am actually trying to do what you say -- append to the current HTML. I'm appending another file to the current file.

maps.php is the current file. The select value will post to maps_append.php and maps_append.php will append to maps.php

Comment: Oh. Yes. I see that. That seems like it will work. I'll go ahead and try this method, but will is it a bad idea to use a method that is generally for a "remote" file when my file is actually on my local web server?

I mean, this will work. But, is it bad practice?

Comment: I apologize... I don't see how this will work. I can't reload the page until after jQuery/AJAX has loaded more form inputs. I need what one form input is to change what form input comes next. 

When the submit button is pushed, then the page will reload.

Comment: It seems like this method uses $_GET, which would be fine, except I don't really understand the syntax of jQuery so I'm not sure where I'd even start with this code.

Comment: Also, it seems to use a link rather than button... :(

Comment: ...What I already have loads the value of the select statement into the div tag. All I need it to do is post that value to another file and append the results to the current page...

Comment: Hogan, I've made a small break through. I've got the maps_append.php to append to maps.php. Now all I need to do is post the select tag value to maps_append.php . Please seen OP edit.

Comment: Typically you would post the value via a web service call in AJAX.